# How to get rid of this extra text around my Bokeh graph (Flask Web Application)

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I'm trying to integrate a Bokeh chart in my Flask Web Application (which I succeeded), the slider works also perfectly. But I get some extra code around my chart as you can see on the pic below. Can anyone tell me why I get this extra text and how to get rid of it?

Thank you

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

@app.route('/graph')
def graph():
    x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
    y = x

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

    plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
    plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

    callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
            var data = source.data;
            var f = cb_obj.value
            var x = data['x']
            var y = data['y']
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
            }
            source.change.emit();
        """)

    slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power")
    slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

    layout = column(slider, plot)

    script, div = components({"plot": plot,"slider":column(slider)})
    kwargs = {'script': script, 'div': div}
    kwargs['title'] = 'bokeh-with-flask' 

    return render_template('graph.html', **kwargs)
```

Here is the HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{ title }}</title>

<link
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/1.2.0/bokeh.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/1.2.0/bokeh-widgets.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <link
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/1.2.0/bokeh-tables.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Chart</h1>
        {{ div|safe }}
        {{ script|safe }}
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/1.2.0/bokeh.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/1.2.0/bokeh-widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/1.2.0/bokeh-tables.js"></script>
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

I get the following result:
[image]

Comment: I think `components()` returns something you don't expect - likely a dict in `div`... Print those out to console and look at what might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```py
    script, div = components({"plot": plot,"slider":column(slider)})
    kwargs = {'script': script, 'div': div}
```

with

```py
    script, (plot_div, slider_div) = components((plot, column(slider)))
    kwargs = {'script': script, 'plot_div': plot_div, 'slider_div': slider_div}
```

and

```
        {{ div|safe }}
        {{ script|safe }}
```

with

```
        {{ plot_div|safe }}
        {{ slider_div|safe }}
        {{ script|safe }}
```

Alternatively, since you embed them directly one after another, just wrap them together in a `column` and pass it to `components` instead of passing multiple roots separately.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I tested Eugene's solution, and it works perfectly also!**

Ok, I found a solution (even though not very elegant I think) thanks to AKS' response:

There was indeed an issue with "div" as he said.
So I printed it out and I got this:

```
{'plot': '\n<div class="bk-root" id="8cb7e626-f766-451b-86c9-2a4b0e22fdab" data-root-id="2881"></div>', 'slider': '\n<div class="bk-root" id="37b8cf2e-8889-4c9e-804d-9b6d65fedf0f" data-root-id="2921"></div>'}
```

I added this to my initial code to modify "div". It was expecting a html type string, and not a dic type string:

```
a = div['plot']
b = div['slider']
div = a+b
```

Followed by my previous code:

```
  kwargs = {'script': script, 'div': div}
  kwargs['title'] = 'bokeh-with-flask'
```

[image]